# What is the visualisation in the picture called

Tags: terminology, data-visualisation

While browsing online I found an interesting triangular visualization and was wondering if it has a name.

[image]

The source of the image is https://www.studioterp.nl/carbon-taxes-a-datavisualization-for-scientific-american/

Comment: Not sure if this has a name, but I have 0 idea what it's trying to show so I don't recommend using it.

Comment: To add to @ZachSaucier point, among other things, there is the issue of not knowing wheter the number is represented by the *size* (i.e. length of a side) or the *area* of the shape. That is the difference between the median in your screenshot being half of the revenue square or a quarter of it. This alone makes understanding the relations between values unnecessarily hard, even if the rest was clear.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply called an infographic, or chart.

Answer (score 0):

No name available here, but three quantities (CO2 tax rate, the revenue of the tax and which percentage of the emission right payments are covered by the CO2 tax) are shown for each country. The median values are shown for comparison.

The basic idea is to present the numbers as surface areas of planar shapes instead of commonly used bar heights or sector angles. That makes possible to have larger variations without making the biggest visualization shapes too big or the smallest ones too small. That's caused by the fact that to make the area say 10x as big one must scale the the sides of the shapes only to 316% ; that's the square root of 10.

Even larger variations could be shown in the same image without sacrificing the proportionality nor the visibility by presenting the numbers as the volumes of simple 3D shapes, like cubes, spheres etc...